# Multigroup (CCK3) / FlexiField-like solution for compound fields?

Tags: 7, nodes

I've used [FlexiField](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) in the past to do multiply occurring series of field groups; now, working on a Drupal 7 project, I'm setting up a "Resume" content type and need a way to set up repetitive entries for education/work experience.

IE: for "Education", I need the ability to dynamically add new rows comprised of a combination of dates and places for each institution studied at.

**What is the best way to accomplish CCK3 multigroup/FlexiField-like functionality in Drupal 7?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment, I'm implementing this via [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection). Granted, that is still very early development.

If somebody could provide a list of solutions in the "group content fields together and allow an infinite number of these groups via the 'add another' button", I'll accept that as my answer. I may have to upgrade my [FlexiField](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) project to D7 at some point and there's currently no clear upgrade path with that module.

Comment: Accepting my own answer as it seems Field Collection is becoming somewhat of the standard for multifields in D7. Please comment if I am incorrect in stating this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Drupal 6, there is a submodule called multigroup that allows you to group multiple fields together (creates the relationship) and gives you the ability to add unlimited values of each group.

If you are doing this in D7, you can use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module, which does the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Drupal 7. Sorry I did not mentioned it. Will edit my post right now. And I can't seems to find multigroup for Drupal 7

Comment: drupal.org/project/field_collection

Comment: Tried that too, but it does not seems to work properly, it does not appear in the structure menu, neither when acceding it directly at website.com/admin/structure/field-collections

Comment: Try running the dev version. It got a release a couple of days ago.

Comment: There is also an alternative, however it works for two text fields only http://drupal.org/project/double_field (which probably does not meet your spec, but worth a look for anyone else stumbling upon this).

Comment: Guess I'll try to tweak it, it seems to be my best way to meet my spec. Thanks, upvoted everything for thanking your speed !

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [Composed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/composed_field). The main difference is that it saves each collection of fields as a field, where as [Field Collection module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) saves each collection of fields as an entity (node). Although it's an awesome module, Composed Field is currently in pre-beta, so you might want to stick with Field Collection for now.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind on this is if you are using Field Collections then you need to make sure to set the value of "Number of values" to more than one (1) if you want the field collection to repeat.

I banged my head on that for a little while before realizing the obvious when I was trying to alter an existing field collection in Profile2 (Recruiter distro).

Answer (score 0):

New answer to an old question (but isn't that how Drupal usually works): you might want to try the [Multifield module](https://drupal.org/project/multifield) as an alternative to Field Collection or the other solutions posted here. It's meant for this type of problem.